# In Django is it possible to default an integer field based on a float field?

Tags: python, django, django-models

Looking to create default based on another field, something along the lines of:

```
class Track(models.Model):
    distance = models.FloatField()
    timeout = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField(default=int(distance * 2))
```

However this throws `TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for *: 'FloatField' and 'int'`

FWIW, I tried this to no avail:

```
class Track(models.Model):
    distance = models.FloatField()
    timeout = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField()

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if (self.timeout is None):
            self.timeout = int(self.distance * 2)
            super(Track, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

But that was throwing `TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Opps, should've read the stack trace more closely, turns out the problem was a bug in my unit test rather than the actual code:

```
def test_timeout_defaults_to_twice_distance_when_none(self):
    Track.objects.create(name='Test Track', distance=10)
    track = Track.objects.get(1) # Should've been get(id=1)
    self.assertEqual(20, track.timeout)
```

I won't delete this question in case another Python and Django noob does the same thing :)